# Nginx Config Location Regex With Language Code In Url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex, url, regular-expressions

Trying to achieve constant language code in url's 1st segment with nginx regex location configuration and could not find the correct syntax.

Necessary result:

- example.com **stays** example.com
- example.com/en **stays** example.com/en
- example.com/en/ **stays** example.com/en **or** example.com/en/ (don't care)
- example.com/en/etc **stays** example.com/en/etc
- example.com/etc **changes to** example.com/en/etc
- example.com/etc/segment **changes to** example.com/en/etc/segment

Currently I have found out this code but it still stuck in somewhere. It makes permanent loop and doesn't not use $1 argument.

```
location ~ "^/(?![a-z]{2}/)(.+)$" {
    rewrite / /en/$1 permanent;
}

#Using handler here for removing index.php in uri (example.com/index.php -> example.com);
location / {
    index index.htm index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Answer can be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913261/2662849

Answer (score 0):

The `@handler` location will rewrite the URI to `/index.php` which is then redirected to `/en/index.php`, which (if it doesn't exist) invokes the `@handler` location.

Read [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) because you need something to handle PHP. The redirect loop is caused because the file or handler does not exist. You need to define a location to handle PHP files, either another regex location or your named location.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best expert in nginx regex url rewriting. Can You please give me a hint with a changing code snippet?

Comment: The url changes to example.com/en/ and it goes into an infinite loop.